# comment from database in EF

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, comments

Is it possible to import oracle database comment on columns of table into generated EF classes as [DisplayName("column comment")] annotation for every generated property?

for example you have this Table

```
employee
column-name   type          comment
ID            integer       Personnel Code
NAME          varchar2(30)  Employee Name
ADDData       date          Start Date
```

and when create EF class from this table I like have this generated class

```
public class Employee
{
    [DisplayName("Personnel Code")]
    public int Id { set; get; }

    [DisplayName("Employee Name")]
    public string Name { set; get; }

    [DisplayName("Start Date")]
    public DateTime AddDate { set; get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate your Entity Contexts & POCOs with T4 text templates.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit)

> Microsoft's Text Template Transformation Toolkit (usually referred to as "T4") is a template based text generation framework included with Visual Studio. T4 source files are usually denoted by the file extension ".tt".
>
> T4 is used by developers as part of an application or tool framework to automate the creation of text files with a variety of parameters. These text files can ultimately be any text format, such as code (for example C#), XML, HTML or XAML.

There's a video example by Julie Lerman [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff717739.aspx).

[Here](https://github.com/damieng/DamienGKit/tree/master/T4/MultipleOutputHelper) is a great utility for creating multiple files from a single T4 template.